# chrome extension not detecting single click

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

so i am working on a chrome extension which basically detects single click and double click,
the content.js code

```
if (!window.recordStepsInjected) {
  window.recordStepsInjected = true;
  console.log("Page URL:", window.location.href);
  document.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    console.log("Clicked:", event.target);
  });
  document.addEventListener("dblclick", function (event) {
    console.log("Double Clicked:", event.target);
  });
}
```

the above code is working for everything except for the element below, double click is working but not single click

```
<a class="menu-link without-sub" href="/projects"><div class="d-flex"><span class="menu-icon"> 
<span class="svg-icon svg-icon-2">
<svg width="20" height="25" viewBox="0 0 20 25" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="mh-50px">
<path>...path code</path>
</svg>
</span>
</span>
<span class="menu-title white-color">About</span>
</div></a>
```

let me know if you have any questions

i have tried using event.stopPropagation(); but it didn't help, also when i click on svg it is working, but the span single click is not being recorded

Comment: 1) Replace `document` with `window` and add `,true` to addEventListener. 2) In addition to that switch to `mousedown` and manually measure the difference since the last `performance.now()` stored in a global variable.

Comment: replacing document with window worked for me, can you explain the 2nd, I am new to this and not sure what's performance.now()